# Chromium Renderer process crashing - on version 8.6.0 and above

Tags: electron, cypress, chromium

When running tests on **Cypress 8.6.0** and above, we get the following error:

[image: Chromium Renderer process just crashed]

Full version info:

[image]

- Cypress package version: 8.6.0
- Cypress binary version: 8.6.0
- Electron version: 14.1.0
- Bundled Node version: 14.17.0

The tests works fine, and we got no render issue on versions below **8.6.0**, such as **8.5.0**. They start to appear in version **8.6.0**.

Full version info from one of the working releases:

[image]

- Cypress package version: 8.5.0
- Cypress binary version: 8.5.0
- Electron version: 13.2.0
- Bundled Node version: 14.16.0

Perhaps there's something in the new version of Electron/Chromium, bundled with **Cypress 8.6.0**, that makes it crash?

How could one go on about trobuleshooting this further? Is there any way to run the specific version of Electron (headless) manually on the machine, to see if it works at all with that version of Chromium?

Any input is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is this happening on your local or CI? Is it possible to update to a more recent version, maybe pre10?

Comment: Hello @jjhelguero, this is happening on CI. Unfortunately, at the moment it's not possible to update to a more recent version. Need to find the root cause as of why it stops working when switching to this version (and higher), before doing so.